# Finding the number of newspapers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A certain school has 300 students every student reads 5 newspapers and every newspaper is read by 60 students then find the number of newspapers?

Comment: is the answer 25?

Comment: @Ramana It seems so, though I can't prove it.

Answer (score 3):

$300 \cdot 5 = 1500$ "readings"

Numbers of "readings" = $n \cdot 60$

where $n$ ist the number of newspapers.

So $60 n = 1500$ and therefore $n = 25$

Answer (score 0):

Please Note: I made the assumption that each student has his own copy of newspaper.

Since, There are 300 students reading 5 newspapers each, so Therefore there must be 1500 newspapers copies.

Since each Newspaper is read by 60 students$\implies$ Each newspaper has 60 copies.

So  Total number of different Newspapers required = $\dfrac{1500}{60}=25$.

Answer (score 0):

Just yet another way to visualize the problem.

Assume each newspaper has 60 distinct articles and the case scenario is that a student reads only one article from each paper and blackens (using a sketch pen) that very article. This ensures every newspaper is read by 60 people.

Every student reads five newspapers. This means they read 5 articles, say everyday. Number of students are 300. This means total number of articles is $300\times5=1500$, which is distributed into $n$ newspapers such that $n\times60=1500$ (total number of articles must me the same in both ways). This gives n=$\frac{1500}{60}=25$.